# How many miners were operating mines in "Civilization"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In [the episode "Civilization"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Civilization_(episode)), close to the episode finale we can see an underground mining facility. It is shown in a very quick cameo, yet I am pretty sure that it is large enough to be operated by a lot of people. I think I can even see some of them walking through corridors seen in that cameo.

Yet in one of the episode's final scenes Captain Archer says:

> that there are only three aliens to beam aboard the alien vessel.

Was the mining facility fully automated and there was actually no one seen in the cameo?